# Iterate a list within a dictionary in ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

I have a variable structured like this. I have successfully used this with `with_dict` with a single key in the `accessible_from`

```
vars:
  mysql_dbs:
    db1:
      user: db1_user
      pass: "password"
      accessible_from: localhost
    db2:
      user: db2_user
      pass: "password2"
      accessible_from: '%'
```

This is applied using the `mysql_db` ansible module, like this:

```
- name: Configure mysql users
  mysql_user: name={{ item.value.user }} password={{ item.value.pass }} host={{ item.value.accessible_from | default('localhost')}} priv={{ item.key }}.*:ALL state=present
  with_dict: "{{ mysql_dbs }}"
```

I would like `accessible_from` to have the ability to be a list. It doesn't matter if it *has* to be a list, but a single key/value pair is not enough :) So for example:

```
vars:
  mysql_dbs:
    db1:
      user: db1_user
      pass: "password"
      accessible_from:
        - server1
        - server2
        - localhost
    db2:
      user: db2_user
      pass: "password"
      accessible_from:
        - '%'
```

So - the aim is to create all the DBs and users in one play. I've tried playing around with `with_subelements`, without success. Is it actually possible to do this? Or is it necessary to restructure the data, or rewrite the play? I'll do that if I have to, but I was wondering if there was another way round it.

Answer (score 3):

**First:** You may refactor your `mysql_dbs` into list (because in `with_subelements` you can't refer items' keys), like:

```
mysql_dbs:
  - name: db1
    user: db1_user
    pass: "password"
    accessible_from:
      - server1
      - server2
      - localhost
  - name: db2
    user: db2_user
    pass: "password2"
    accessible_from: 
      - '%'
```

And user `with_subelements`:

```
- mysql_user: name={{ item[0].user }} password={{ item[0].pass }} host={{ item[1] }} priv={{ item[0].name }}.*:ALL state=present
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ mysql_dbs }}"
    - accessible_from
```

But this will fail if `accessible_from` is undefined for any db. You may use `skip_missing`, but this will skip entire db. So you can't omit `accessible_from` in this case.

**Second:** You may use helper `set_fact` to form a list with key and value, also defaulting `accessible_from` to `localhost`. This will work without refactoring your data:

```
- set_fact:
    db_name: "{{ item.key }}"
    db_params: "{{ dict(accessible_from=['localhost']) | combine(item.value) }}"
  with_dict: "{{ mysql_dbs }}"
  register: mysql_dbs_fact
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"

- debug:
    msg: "mysql_user: name={{ item[0].db_params.user }} password={{ item[0].db_params.pass }} host={{ item[1] }} priv={{ item[0].db_name }}.*:ALL state=present"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ mysql_dbs_fact.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts') | list }}"
    - db_params.accessible_from
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item[0].db_name }}->{{ item[1] }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 vars:
     mysql_dbs:
       db1:
         user: db1_user
         pass: "password"
         accessible_from:
           - acc_from: server1
           - acc_from: server2
           - acc_from: localhost
       db2:
         user: db2_user
         pass: "password"
         accessible_from:
           - acc_from: '%'
      tasks:
      - name: Configure mysql users
        debug: msg="{{ item.0.user }} password={{ item.0.pass }} host={{ item.1.acc_from }} priv={{ item.0 }}.*:ALL state=present"
        with_subelements:
           - "{{ mysql_dbs }}"
           - accessible_from
```

Comment: I suppose this `"{{ mysql_dbs | default('localhost')}}"` will default to string `localhost`, when entire `mysql_dbs` object is undefined...

Comment: Wrong cut and paste. Removed default. Thanks, @KonstantinSuvorov